# Metarial UI useMediaQuery hooks render twice to React Component, do you have any solution for it?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI in the project and need to check the current breakpoint to render div for mobile, but each time for the first render **isMobile** and **isDesktop** value return **false** but then it set the correct value after second render.
It works well from UI side, but I would like to avoid the first unnecessary render if it's possible?

```
const curTheme = useTheme();
const isMobile = useMediaQuery(curTheme.breakpoints.down("sm"));
const isDesktop = useMediaQuery(curTheme.breakpoints.up("md"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add noSsr option

```
const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)', { noSsr: true });
```