# Redux state not dispatched on page load

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I can't find the reason why my redux state is not dispatched when the page loads, even if there is a dispatch event when the Component mounts

Here is a basic example of my problem:

```
export const SET_SITE_NAME = "SET_SITE_NAME";
```

Actions:

```
import {SET_SITE_NAME} from "./AppBarTypes";

export const setSiteName = (state) => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: SET_SITE_NAME,
        payload: state
    })
}
```

Reducer:

```
import {SET_SITE_NAME} from "./AppBarTypes";

const initialState = {
    state: "Dashboard"
}

export const appBarReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_SITE_NAME:
            return {
                ...state,
                state: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Basic usage:

```
function ProjectsList(props) {
   
    useEffect(() => {
        props.setSiteName("Projects");
    }, []);

    return (
        <Main open={props.drawer.state}>
        </Main>
    );
}

ProjectsList.propTypes = {
    setSiteName: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    projects: state.projects,
    drawer: state.drawer
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    getProjects,
    setSiteName
})(withRouter(ProjectsList));
```

From what I was able to debug, the setSiteName function runs and it always receives the correct state.
Also, if I navigate to other Component on the site and back to this Component, it loads the state perfectly, so I assume the implementation is correct.

**Edit**

I have created a working example where I was able to trace back the problem.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sf1fmj?file=src%2FApp.js

The problem is related to `useMediaQuery`. As you can see in the example, if you uncomment that part, the default redux state 'Dashboard' will be shown instead of the 'Projects' state which is set.

Though I don't know why this causes this problem and how I could solve it. As you can see, in this example I don't even use that value, just query it...

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example on https://stackblitz.com/? if possible.that will be really helpful to run and answer.

Comment: I have tried recreating the same app but it won't even start here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ix62ac?file=src/Demo.js

Though you can clearly see that the state is set with the reducer state

Comment: Well, I have fixed the problems on stackblitz.io and it works there flawlessly... Though in my projects it is much more complex, so I don't know what can cause side effects like this.

Comment: I have found the error, but I don't know why this happens:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sf1fmj?file=src%2FApp.js
If I use `useMediaQuery` for checking dark mode you can see in the example that 'Hello Dashboard' is returned (default redux state). If you remove that, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change this:

```
const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
```

to this:

```
const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)', { noSsr: true });
```

[Metarial UI useMediaQuery hooks render twice to React Component, do you have any solution for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66922595/metarial-ui-usemediaquery-hooks-render-twice-to-react-component-do-you-have-any)

According to docs, you can set this to false if you are not doing any server side rendering:

> Options.noSsr (Boolean [optional]): Defaults to false. In order to perform the server-side rendering reconciliation, it needs to render twice. A first time with nothing and a second time with the children. This double pass rendering cycle comes with a drawback. It's slower. You can set this flag to true if you are not doing server-side rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing React Thunk to your middlewares https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk.
That way, you can use this syntax:

```js
function incrementAsync() {
  return dispatch => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Yay! Can invoke sync or async actions with `dispatch`
      dispatch(increment())
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

## Edit

I believe you are missing  the dispatch... You can do it basically in two ways: literally call dispatch to dispatch your actions, or, map your dispatch actions with a mapDispatchToProps function like so:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    siteName: ()=> dispatch(siteNameAction())
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

So using the approach shown above, you can simply call `this.props.siteName()`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include this, but I think it is there:
`const middleware = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)];

    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer(history),
        applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    );`

Comment: @KristofRado so in that case I believe you are missing your "matchDispatchToProps". I am going to include that on my answer.

Comment: Please see this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ix62ac?file=src/Demo.js
This is how it is setup basically and it works here perfectly. So I assume that this part of my code is correct, so maybe the problem is somewhere else (which is not included in this stripped version).

Comment: The problem is related to setting dark mode